# Export VM from ESXi embedded host client Failed - Network Error or network interruption

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm trying to export a 60 GB VM from VMware ESXi to my computer via the ESXi embedded host client. Each time i try, it gets about 20 GB of `disk-0.vmdk` file downloaded (downloading ~1GB/min) and then it stops with `Network Error`

- VMware ESXi v6.5.0 (build 4887370)
- ESXi embedded host client version 1.23.0 (build 6360286)
- The "Recent Task" pane says 'Completed successfully' next to Export
  Vm.
- I have no snapshots attached to this vm
- The destination location has 200GB of free space.
- Host and web client connected over ethernet (not wifi).

I've tried 3 times now and it keeps failing. Any idea what the root problem is? Is there another way to export the vm without shutting down the host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known issue](https://labs.vmware.com/flings/esxi-embedded-host-client/bugs/516). Based on the referenced thread, exporting large VM's via the embedded host client has some bugs and a reliable work around is to use the [OVF Tool](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/ovf/) which is available for Windows, Linux (yeah!) and Mac.

You can also connect to the ESXi Host via VMware Workstation and then select the VM, and in the menu select VM > Manage > Download. It will download as OVF template.

[image]

Comment: ```Transfer failed 
Error: execution aborted```

Export using ovftool failed with this message after exporting around 20GB. What could be the reason?